# Xcode window organization tips?

Tags: xcode, macos, ide

I'm a fairly recent convert to Xcode and OS X. Even though I have two large monitors it feels likes I spend far to much time hunting for windows.

I typically have at least the following windows open:

- The file I'm editing.
- A matching header file.
- Another source file.
- API Documentation.
- A browser window.

It seems like whatever I want next is *always* underneath something else. There are lots of ways to switch windows (e.g., Exposé, Spaces, OS X hotkeys, Xcode hotkeys), but that's part of the problem. There are so many different approaches, I can't blindly use one; I have to think about which is the right one for each situation.

How do *you* organize *your* Xcode windows so you aren't switching all the time?

Or, how do you effectively switch between windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer all-in-one layout (Xcode's preferences->General). If I need to look at several files simultaneously, I split the editor view (the little button above the vertical scroller). I also constantly use Cmd-Option-UpArrow to switch between .h and .m files. The only other window I have is the documentation browser.

I have a dedicated Space for Xcode so that I can switch between Xcode and Safari with a shortcut.

Xcode is unbelievably customizable, though many options are well hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I keep the main XCode window open and the documentation open slightly askew from each other horizontally so i can click one while the other is on top. I use the button (right next to the lock icon) which opens the associated file to toggle in-betweeen the h and m files.

I use expose and keep safari in another panel.

Comment: You can assign a keyboard shortcut to the **Switch to Header/Source File** menu item switch between .h and .m files quickly. Also, don't forget the built-in Mac OS X shortcut **⌘-`** to switch between open windows in an app.

Comment: Whoa, I spent like 2 years looking for a damn button to switch between windows. If I could, I would give you 100 points or something like that!